# Proper log level handling on GCP

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, abseil

I run some TensorFlow code on GCP instances. All logs generated are saved in StackDriver, but most of them are saved as "error" messages.

```
{
 [...]
 labels: {
  [...]
  container.googleapis.com/stream: "stderr"   
 }
 severity: "ERROR"  
 textPayload: "INFO:root:Is GPU available? True"  
}
```

As you can see here I logged the GPU availability with `logging.info` (from the Python library), but it is output on `stderr` and so considered as an `"ERROR"` by StackDriver (marking it with an orange exclamation mark).

The three of `logging`, `absl.logging` and `tf.print` result in the log message appearing as error message.

Is there a way to configure the TF logger to avoid `stderr` output, or make it behave nicely with GCP StackDriver?